# Detect if the iframe content has loaded successfully

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cross-domain

I have a widget that contains an iframe. The user can configure the url of this iframe, but if the url could not be loaded (it does not exists or the user does not have access to internet) then the iframe should failover to a default offline page.

The question is, how can I detect if the iframe could be loaded or not? I tried subscribing to the 'load' event, and, if this event is not fired after some time then I failover, but this only works in Firefox, since IE and Chrome fires the 'load' event when the "Page Not Found" is displayed.

Comment: hey skinssay, did you find any solution without using a proxy?

Comment: no, I haven't. I made a deeper research and I think it is not possible :(

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552355/prevent-iframe-this-webpage-is-not-available-error-from-displaying-on-website the onerror property is supported by webkit but i didn't got any luck to make it work. did you?

Comment: As of Chrome 35 at least the onerror is not supported by iframe. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365457#c4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nowadays the browsers have a series of security limitations that keep you away from the content of an iframe (if it isn´t of your domain).

If you really need that functionality, you have to build a server page that have to work as a proxy, that receive the url as a parameter, test if it is a valid url, and does the redirect or display the error page.

Answer (score 15):

I found the following link via Google: http://wordpressapi.com/2010/01/28/check-iframes-loaded-completely-browser/

Don't know if it solves the 'Page Not Found' issue.

```
<script type="javascript">
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "http://www.your_iframe.com/";
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1 && !window.opera) {
  iframe.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (iframe.readyState == "complete"){
      alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
    }
  };
} else {
  iframe.onload = function(){
    alert("Iframe is now loaded.");
  };
}
</script>
```

I haven't tried it myself, so I don't know if it works. Good luck!

Comment: This works pretty much like the onload event, the (iframe.readyState == "complete") condition is true even if the loaded page is an IE error page. So, it let me know when the page has loaded, but not if it was successfully loaded. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thank you! I've been scouring for a working solution for 2 hours. Finally! :)

Comment: Does not work in Chrome:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952942/iframe-readystate-does-not-work-in-chrome

Comment: iframes are NOT XMLHttpRequests !, no this doesn't work.

Comment: Best answer! Working fine on chrome.

Answer (score 6):

If you control the content of the iframe, the iframe can send a message to the parent.

```
        parent.postMessage('iframeIsDone', '*');
```

The parent callback listens for the message.

```
        var attachFuncEvent = "message";
        var attachFunc = window.addEventListener ;
        if (! window.addEventListener) {
            attachFunc = window.attachEvent;
            attachFuncEvent = "onmessage";
        }

        attachFunc(attachFuncEvent, function(event) {
            if (event.data ==  'iframeIsDone') { // iframe is done callback here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

How about checking if the url is available and only then setting the actual url of the iframe?
e.g. with JQuery

```
var url = "google.com"
var loading_url = "/empty.html"
document.getElementById("iframe").src = loading_url;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
         if(e.status === 200){
              document.getElementById("iframe").src = url;
         }
    }
});
```

Edit:
This does not seem to work cross domain, the status code is 0 in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the contents of the iframe (e.g. you can add arbitrary code to the page), you can try to implement a special function in each of them, then in your page, you call that function and catch an error (via `window.onerror` handler) if the function called via eval fails because the page didn't load.

Here's example code: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1114265&page=420

Comment: since he put the tag "cross-domain" I would imagine he doesn't control both sides.

Comment: Yes, i don't have control over the content. The idea is that the user can configure the iframe's src with whatever url he wants.

Comment: eval is evil. iframe with eval is satanic.
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.google.com" onLoad="eval(str);"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

After the onload fires, you can scavenge the content of the iframe to see if it contains a usefull page or not. You'd have to make this browser specifuc unfortunately because they all display a different "page not found" message.

For more info, take a look here at http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/

Comment: Yes you are right, it will not let you access cross-domain content.