# How to catch onload event in one frame fired from another frame

Tags: javascript

I have a frameset with two frames. Upper frame reloads a document in the lower frame by changing its location property. I need to catch in the upper frame the onload event fired in the lower frame.
This code does not work, though no errors are produced either:

```
//this script runs in frames[0]
top.frames[1].location = "test.htm";
top.frames[1].onload = function( ) { alert('Thanks!'); };
```

The test,htm is loaded in the lower frame, but the alert does not appear.
What is the easiest way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: See the last answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548984/detect-if-the-iframe-content-has-loaded-successfully

Comment: Hi, glortho! Thanks for the help! I coded a workaround: I catch the onload event of the lower frame in the lower frame, and from that event I call a function in the upper frame. This will suffice for now. I just wonder if it is possible to catch the onload event if the lower frame comes from a different domain and I do not have control over its code.