Google Docs iframe not loading sometimes
When I try to load an iframe with the src
https://docs.google.com/gview?url=MY_URL&embedded=true

Sometimes it loads and sometimes it doesn't
I tried changing the pdf url and the problem kept happening
I tried visiting the link directly in the browser and sometimes it loads sometimes nothing happens
Is there any solution or alternative?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627844/embedded-google-document-in-iframe-sometimes-doesnt-load

I just solved the problem all I had to do is keep sending http requests  to the url and once I get html response ( not empty one) I make it the srcdoc of the iframe

Can you please provide some more details? Thanks

you make an http request to the google docs url and then you will recive an html. use this html as the srcdoc for the iframe (add a base url so it works properly)
