# Iframe error handling (error 324, cross domain)

Tags: javascript, iframe, onerror

I'm using an iframe with a cross-domain content inside. I'd like to apply so error handling in case errors are returned. I've already read [Prevent iframe "This webpage is not available." error from displaying on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552355/prevent-iframe-this-webpage-is-not-available-error-from-displaying-on-website?answertab=votes#tab-top) which is pretty similar. Altho I'd like to avoid using HTML 5 specification element and stick to XHTML1.0. Is there any JS based solution? (sorry if asking obvious - I'm not rly good in JS)

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please see [Other Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705083/how-can-i-handle-errors-in-loading-an-iframe) in stackoverflow.com. I think your question is answered there.